# Types default alignment in visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, memory-alignment

Just noticed something that looks strange to me. Visual C++ doesn't align object in their required boundary by default. For example long long is aligned to 4 bytes boundary, while __alignof(T) returns 8 (as far as I see it always returns size of the type). So it looks like it is not properly aligned. For example

```
long long a1;
char g;
long long a2;
// alignment check for &a2 fails
if (((uintptr_t)&a2 & (__alignof(long long) - 1)) != 0) // failed
```

I also tried just to print the pointer, the value of `&a2` is `0x0035F8FC`(`3537148` in dec).

Is there something I get wrong? I need properly aligned object of type long long. What can I do about that?
I could use `__declspec(align())` Microsoft extension, but it requires literal number, so I can't write anything like that.

```
__declspec(align(__alignof(long long))) long long object;
```

Comment: What exactly was the checked that you performed? I tried this myself and found that a1 and a2 have precisely 8 bytes between them, as expected.

Comment: @Ken Wayne VanderLinde: The question is not about structure alignment. I just create variable in stack and it is not aligned properly.

Comment: does the documentation state that stack variables are aligned?

Comment: @David: I guess they supposed to be aligned, otherwise alignment is useless at all. I can create aligned structure object in stack and if that object will not be aligned properly then whole alignment of structure is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VC doesn't guarantee automatic stack alignment of variables, at most the variable will be aligned to the stacks alignment(generally 4 bytes on 32 bit systems). If you need special alignment, you need to use `__declspec(align(x))`, just like MSVC's SSE types(like `__m128`), else you'll need to use `_aligned_malloc` instead

Comment: Thanks. I don't need special alignment, I need proper alignment for specified type. __alignof says that 8 bytes boundary is a proper alignment for long long, so the variable is not properly aligned. I can put this variable into some structure, however it will not help, because if I create object of that structure in stack it still will be not properly aligned. Some CPU's may throw an error if I try to work with unaligned objects, so this default behavior of VC may not work on those CPU's. Am I wrong? Should I use __declspec(align) to make simple application work?

Comment: @ledokol: if your gonna be putting it into a structure, you need to align both the struct and the element, however, the only stuff I've come across that will error if missaligned is SSE ops, but even SSE has unaligned ops

Comment: I'm going to use that variable for atomic operations. Load and store are guaranteed to be atomic on x86 for aligned data, but x86 requires quadword to be aligned to 64 bit boundary (`Reading or writing a quadword aligned on a 64-bit boundary`).

Answer (score 0):

The alignment should minimize the memory cycles on RAM access. The 4 byte alignment uses only two 32-bit acccesses to the  `long long`. The 8 byte aligment doesn't improve the behavior. The compiler has a default alignment that can be overwritten with the `/Zp` option.

See also: Configuration Properties   C/C++  Code Generation  Struct Member Aligment.

Comment: I just need properly aligned variable and by default it should be properly aligned, but __alignof says that there is another requirement for that type (8 bytes) and check fails. Do you mean that __alignof is wrong? Then how can I get required alignment for the type?